# NodeJS route changes not being updated but new routes work properly

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

I need to make some changes in an old legacy code which I don't know much about, and I'm experiencing something very confusing.

the route is defined like this

```
app.get('/getMapProduct',billing.getMapProdut);
```

and I need to change to content being returned in from the function `billing.getMapProdut`
I changed the logic of the function but calling the route still returns according to the old logic.

I added a new route calling the same function

```
app.get('/test',billing.getMapProdut);
```

and it returns like expected, with the new logic.

Next, I've tried to change the name of the original function to:

```
app.get('/getMapProducttt',billing.getMapProdut);
```

`getMapProducttt` doesn't work (not found), the old route still works.

The next try is the most weird to me, I've tried adding a new route called `getMapProducttt`, but unlike `test`, this one didn't work. Yet, adding a route called `getMapProd` does work like `test`.

Next, I've tried commenting out the original route, but, you guessed it, still works.
I've also tried changing the name of the entire file containing all of the routes. The 'test' one doesn't work anymore, but the 'getMapProduct' still works.

I've searched the entire codebase, there's no other definition of a route called `getMapProduct`, and no other definition of the function being called from it, `getMapProdut`.

The only direction I'm able to think of is some sort of weird cache mechanism, but I can't think of where or how is it defined.

I'm afraid it might be something really silly, but I can't think of anything. any ideas?

Comment: Evident question, but first thing that came into my mind. Do you restart the server after each change?

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu, yeah of course. Otherwise the new route would take affect either I think. Either way I made sure to restart many times during debugging this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually really silly, though still some of the scenarios that happened aren't clear to me. It was a weirdly setup cache on the CloudFront